# Using gpointer with Python and GObject introspection

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject-introspection

I am learning about Python and Gtk 3, using GObject introspection. I have done some samples, and I am begining to understant how it works. But there is one thing I can't understand, How can I pass a gpointer param?

I trying to use a function who receive a buffer (with gpointer), and I always end with this message:

could not convert value for property `pixels' from LP_c_ubyte to gpointer

(LP_c_ubyte was my last try, but I have prove a lot of types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a pointer in GObject introspection. If the introspected function is one you wrote yourself, then you should [annotate](https://wiki.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Annotations) your parameter documentation with, for example, `(array length=buflen)`, where `buflen` is the name for the parameter that gives the length of the buffer. See the linked page for more information.

If the function is in a library that you didn't write yourself, either look around in the API for a more introspection-friendly function, or file a bug with the library. APIs using bare `gpointer`s shouldn't even be exposed to Python.